MailKit OAuth2 SMTP Office365 Send Mail
Since Microsoft announced it is removing basic auth smtp support, I am trying to find a different way of sending emails from my application. My applications are backend applications so therefore it has to be a non-interactive flow.
When I use the password flow, everything works perfectly, however, password grant flow is legacy since it also exposes the user password:
static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(FormUrlEncodedContent content, string tokenEndpoint)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, content).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
    var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    client.Dispose();

    var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);
    JsonElement root = doc.RootElement;
    if (root.TryGetProperty("access_token", out JsonElement tokenElement))
        return tokenElement.GetString()!;

    throw new Exception("Failed to get access token");
}

static void SendO365(SaslMechanism accessToken, string host, int port, string from, string to)
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

        try
        {
            client.Connect(host, port, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
            client.Authenticate(accessToken);
            var msg = new MimeMessage();
            msg.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(from));
            msg.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(to));
            msg.Subject = "Testing SMTP";
            msg.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = "This is a test message." };
            client.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "yyy"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", "https://outlook.office365.com"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", ".default"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "foo@domain.com"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "zzz"),
});

string tenantId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"
string tokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token";
var accessToken = GetAccessToken(content, tokenEndpoint).Result;

var userEmail = "foo@domain.com";
var smtpServer = "smtp.office365.com";
var smtpPort = 587;
var toEmail = "foo2@domain.com";

SendO365(new SaslMechanismOAuth2(userEmail, accessToken), smtpServer, smtpPort, userEmail, toEmail);

In Entra I have set the Mail.Send scope.
I tried switching to the client_credentials flow since it is more secure but I always get an error Authentication unsuccessful on client.Authenticate(accessToken).
Anyone has an idea?
Edit
GitHub Repository: https://github.com/tsafadi/MailKit-OAuth-SMTP/tree/master/MailKit.SMTP-OAuth

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#add-the-pop-imap-or-smtp-permissions-to-your-entra-ad-application

As you've discovered, you need to use the client-credential workflow.
I have documented what you need to do here: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md (specifically, see the Web Services docs).
Re-posting here to make StackOverflow happy.
Registering Your Application with Microsoft
Whether you are writing a Desktop, Mobile or Web Service application, the first thing you'll need to do is register your
application with Microsoft's Identity Platform. To do this, go to Microsoft's
Quickstart guide
and follow the instructions.
Configuring the Correct API Permissions for Your Application
There are several different API permissions that you may want to configure depending on which protocols your application intends to use.
Follow the instructions for adding the POP, IMAP, and/or SMTP permissions to your Entra AD application.
Web Services
Registering Service Principals for Your Web Service
Once your web service has been registered, the tenant admin will need to register your service principal.
To use the New-ServicePrincipal cmdlet, open an Azure Powershell
terminal and install ExchangeOnlineManagement and connect to your tenant as shown below:
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -allowprerelease
Import-module ExchangeOnlineManagement 
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Organization <tenantId>

Next, register the Service Principal for your web service:
New-ServicePrincipal -AppId <APPLICATION_ID> -ObjectId <OBJECT_ID> [-Organization <ORGANIZATION_ID>]

Granting Permissions for Your Web Service
In order to grant permissions for your web service to access an Office365 and/or Exchange account, you'll need to first get the
Service Principal ID registered in the previous step using the following command:
Get-ServicePrincipal | fl

Once you have the Service Principal ID for your web service, use the following command to add full
mailbox permissions for the email account that your web service will be accessing:
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "john.smith@example.com" -User 
<SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID> -AccessRights FullAccess

Authenticating a Web Service with OAuth2
Now that you have the Client ID and Tenant ID strings, you'll need to plug those values into
your application.
The following sample code uses the Microsoft.Identity.Client
nuget package for obtaining the access token which will be needed by MailKit to pass on to the Exchange
server.
var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create (clientId)
    .WithAuthority ($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0")
    .WithCertificate (certificate) // or .WithClientSecret (clientSecret)
    .Build ();
 
var scopes = new string[] {
    // For IMAP and POP3, use the following scope
    //"https://ps.outlook.com/.default"

    // For SMTP, use the following scope
    "https://outlook.office365.com/.default"
};

var authToken = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient (scopes).ExecuteAsync ();
var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2 (accountEmailAddress, authToken.AccessToken);

using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
    client.Connect ("smtp.office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
    client.Authenticate (oauth2);
    client.Send (message);
    client.Disconnect (true);
}

Additional Resources
For more information, check out the Microsoft.Identity.Client
documentation.

I will try this out, thank you!

I followed everything exaclty like you said but I keep getting 535: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [FR4P281CA0165.DEUP281.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-06-13T14:41:10.853Z 08DC8A68B4EFA073]

Nope, tried it multiple times and even deleted everything but it does not work. There are several things that are confusing to me. Firstly, the article from MSFT you provided which shows how to add permissions to an application shows a screenshot with "SMTP.SendAsApp" which I cannot find. I assume it is now Mail.Send. Furthermore, when I try to create my service principal, I cannot use the app registration object id, I need to use the enterprise application object id. This is all very confusing and I cannot get it to work

I have created a GitHub repository. Maybe you can check it out and see if there is something wrong.

No, the Mail.Send permission is ONLY for the HTTP REST API (aka Microsoft.Graph API) and DOES NOT ALLOW SMTP sending. This is why you are getting failures.

It works, thank you so much! I was indeed using the wrong permission.

I need to use SMTP and IMAP with OAUTH2 on a consumer outlook.com e-mail address (i.e. no active directory).  All the solutions talk about having an Azure tenant with an active subscription. I don't have one of those. How do I use OAUTH2 on a consumer outlook.com e-mail address please with MailKit?

You need an Azure account with a tenant because this is how you register your program. Without that, you can't get a client ID or secret that is needed for the OAuth2 authentication process. Outlook, Thunderbird, etc all have their own client IDs/secrets that the companies owning those apps have registered with Azure. But if you are writing your own program, you'll need your own Azure account. There's no way around that.
